# How to delete a file from a command in a shell file for /etc/init.d?

Tags: linux, bash, script, init

I have a about question working with `/etc/init.d` shell script.

All I want to do is delete a file from a command inside the shell script like so:

```
case $1 in

stop)
  echo "Stopping"
  rm -f /var/run/memcached/memcached.pid

esac
```

I save it as test and create the `memcached.pid` file.

When I run `/etc/init.d/test` stop with the script from within the `/etc/init.d/` folder the `memcached.pid` file does not get deleted.

When I run the script from my home directory, it works fine.

Is there a special format or structure of the command that is needed?

Comment: I run the command as sudo so: sudo /etc/init.d/test stop. Thank you for the link to examples!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the full path to rm; confirm that its the same on your system:

```
 /usr/bin/rm -f /var/run/memcached/memcached.pid
```

init scripts do not have your ( or roots) PATH environment variable set typically.

Comment: I modified the mini script like you have and it still doesn't delete the pid file. This is really strange. There's nothing before it, that snippet is the test script.

Comment: Did you confirm the path to rm ?  Use the command which rm to get its path

Comment: If you have the right path, add the following command prior to the rm; first confirm path to this program as well. /usr/bin/chmod u+w /var/run/memcached/memcached.pid to debug further redirect the output of each command by adding the following line at the end of each: >> /var/logs/initlog.log 2>&1

Comment: Then obviously review that file after it runs

Comment: Yes, I confirmed the right path with all hard coded path. Now trying the debug log.

Comment: The debug log didn't result in a file.

Comment: I managed to make it work like so, not sure what is different from my little test script I started with :-)

PIDFILE="/var/run/memcached/memcached.pid"

printf "%s\n" $PIDFILE

case $1 in

stop)
  echo "Stopping"
  rm -f $PIDFILE

esac

printf "%s\n" $PIDFILE

Comment: I isolated the peculiarity to the line with #. /lib/lsb/init-functions at the top of the actual script and commented it out. The script behaves like a normal bash script. I'm sure it does something important. I'll research it later.

Comment: the . /lib/lsb/init-functions was trying to source a common 'library' that was required to be used in init.d scripts - it's very likely you don't have that installed (or at least in that location) and that line caused an error. Typically an error wouldn't cause the next lines to fail in a normal bash script, unless you had `set -e` or `#!/bin/bash -e`  in the script (or possibly in the higher level init script that calls this one); that flag will cause a script to end execution on the first occurrence of an error. And that would explain why no log files got created - it never got that far.